# Turn traditional websites (HUGO in my case) into an SPA

Tags: javascript, browser, single-page-application, hugo

#### The Problem

I've recently experimented with [HUGO](https://gohugo.io/) and it really surprised me how much I like how simple and fast it is compared to [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) and [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/), the static website builders I've dealt with before.

The most important drawback from my perspective is that Gatsby produces

- traditional static websites, where each site-internal navigation re-requests all common dependencies and loses all state, whereas the other two make
- SPAs, where site-internal navigation does not cause common Javascript to be reprocessed.

While the advantages of SPAs are many, I'm only focusing on the points regarding in-page navigation:

- It's faster. It's important to keep site navigation fast to avoid exposing a re-rendering of common page elements to the user (experienced as annoying flickering of the menus or even the page background). Static website pages can be served in 50ms or so, but browsers usually can't do the rest quickly enough if they need to evaluate the scripts again.
  For example, the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/), built with HUGO and quite responsive, are still not fast enough: It often flickers on navigation - even though the main content is loaded in less than 100ms.
- State can persist. That's important because many Javascript tags used on traditional non-SPA websites can make use of that: For example, a chat window enters the screen in an animation, but *only the first time* - it then just stays where it is on internal navigation.

I'm asking here how I could, while keep using fast and simple HUGO, still at least get these two advantages.

#### A possible solution?

A somewhat hacky but very general approach I could think of would be to write a generic piece of Javascript that, just like SPAs,

- intercepts browser navigation,
- modifies all `a` tags to intercept clicks,
- loads new pages with AJAX on those clicks rather than allowing browser handling,
- change the content and fix the history.

In my case, I'd be perfectly happy to have the restriction to have the same `head` element and immutable outer layout (menus should be within that and still get loaded every time) except for a select few items such as the page title.

So, my questions here are

- Is there an easier way?
- Is there a problem with this approach I don't see?
- Do I have to write this myself or is there already something I could build upon?

Comment: Your possible solution reminds me of https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/README.md

I believe the GitHub website itself loads with a type of PJAX

Comment: I'm fascinated by this. Could you create a SPA - however you want. Which is essentially an "iframe" for the various pages that Hugo built as a "wrapper" so to speak? Is that the idea you are trying to play with?

Comment: Researching forks of `jquery-pjax` lead me to a more modern incarnation, [MoOx/pjax](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax). It works splendidly in my HUGO site and it now feels as speedy and flicker-free as an SPA and I could set it up in minutes. Fantastic!

Comment: @Rogelio Yes. The wrapping part is included in every request but ignored on every one but the first. The version of pjax I now use fishes out a number of configurable blocks to replace in your layout on each navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `turbo by hotwired` in your hugo project, you just need to install it via npm/yarn

> npm i @hotwired/turbo

and then import to your JavaScript config, like this way:

> import * as Turbo from "@hotwired/turbo";

And now your hugo website looks like a SPA web.
Maybe this web will be an example for you : https://www.petanikode.com/